# JavaScript: Bullets and enemy in one array (splice, re-indexed)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, splice

I making simple shooting game and there is a problem (sometimes):

[GIF Game problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Kbr.gif)

3 bullets was removed (but only one bullet collided). Bullets and enemy (blue square) are in one array (var objects = []). Sometimes it destroy (splice) only bullets not enemy.

When i do a .splice(), array is being re-indexed, i know i can use:

- split objects (two arrays for enemy and bullets)
- or use "delete"

But i want use splice() and i want all objects (bullets, enemy) in one array, it possible? Any ideas? I don't need a code (but if someone have a time please update my jsfiddle...). I tried decrement (i--) variable "i" (in loop) after a .splice() - but that does not solve the problem.

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/uy9okuzv/1/ (space == shot, keys == controls)

html

```
<canvas id="game" width="500" height="400" style="border: 1px red solid;">
```

javascript

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("game").getContext('2d');

var objects = [];
var keys = [];
var shotTime = 30;
var ship = {
    x: 20,
    y: 200,
    w: 50,
    h: 50,
}

setInterval(function(){ 
    // controls 
    if(keys[37]){
        ship.x-=4;
    }   
    if(keys[38]){
        ship.y-=4;
    }       
    if(keys[39]){
        ship.x+=4;
    }   
    if(keys[40]){
        ship.y+=4;
    }

    if(keys[32] && shotTime<=0){
        push(ship.x+ship.w, ship.y, "bullet", "red", "left");
        shotTime = 30;
    }else{
        shotTime--;
    }

    // update
    for(var e=0; e<objects.length; e++){
        var obj = objects[e];

        if(obj.type=="bullet"){
            for (var i = 0; i<objects.length; i++) {
                var enemy = objects[i];
                if(enemy.type=="enemy"){
                    if(collisionObj(obj, enemy)){
                        objects.splice(e,1);

                        objects.splice(i,1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(obj.dir=="left"){
            obj.x+=5;
        }       

        if(obj.dir=="right"){
            obj.x--;
        }
    }

    // render
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,game.width, game.height);

    for(var e=0; e<objects.length; e++){
        var obj = objects[e];

        ctx.fillStyle=obj.color;
        ctx.fillRect(obj.x, obj.y, obj.w, obj.h);
    }

    ctx.fillStyle="green";
    ctx.fillRect(ship.x, ship.y, ship.w, ship.h);
},1000/60);

// add enemy
setInterval(function(){
    push(game.width, mt_rand(10,game.height-50), "enemy", "blue", "right");
},1000);

// functions
function collisionObj(obj1, obj2, marginX, marginY){
    if(marginX==null){
        marginX = 0;
    }
    if(marginY==null){
        marginY = 0;
    }
    if(obj1.x < obj2.x + obj2.w-marginX
        && obj1.x + obj1.w-marginX > obj2.x &&
        obj1.y < obj2.y + obj2.h-marginY &&
        obj1.h-marginY + obj1.y > obj2.y){
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function mt_rand(minimum, maximum) {
    minimum = parseInt(minimum, 10);
    maximum = parseInt(maximum, 10);

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
}

function push(x,y, what,color, dir){
    objects.push({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        h: 50,
        w: 50,
        type: what,
        color: color,
        dir: dir,
    });
}

// listeners
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){

    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);
```

Comment: *But i want use splice() and i want all objects (bullets, enemy) in one array* Why? If it causes more problems than it solves, try rethinking your design. For a start, I wouldn't rely on array index as a indicator of identity. Why not have you objects have their own (unchanging) id property?

Comment: don't splice in a loop. It's to expensive; besides the problems. use a `filter()` instead.

Comment: I want to know solution for some (my) mistakes. I still learning javascript. Thanks you for all good idea/suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is along these lines:

```
if(collisionObj(obj, enemy)){
  objects.splice(e,1);
  objects.splice(i,1);
}
```

When you have a collision, you remove both the bullet (index `e`) and the enemy (index `i`). Whenever the enemy index is larger than the bullet's, after removing the bullet, the enemy index won't be correct anymore.

You have to remove the one that comes last first:

```
if(collisionObj(obj, enemy)){
  if( e > i ){
    objects.splice(e,1);
    objects.splice(i,1);
  }
  else{
    objects.splice(i,1);
    objects.splice(e,1);
  }
}
```